# symmetricDS server (postgresql) client (mysql) setup allowing send table schema ignoring FK constraint

Tags: mysql, postgresql, symmetricds

I would like to setup following scenario: server (postgres) is replicated life to client (mysql). Only one direction. I am trying to build this setup using symmetricsDS. The problem occures when I try to send table schema to client node. It always ends up with:

`Cannot add foreign key constraint`

I was trying to set in `.properties` file for client in `/sds/engines`:

`db.init.sql=@@session.foreign_key_checks=0`

I also tried to define extension like this:

```
insert into sym_extension (EXTENSION_ID, EXTENSION_TYPE, INTERFACE_NAME, NODE_GROUP_ID, ENABLED, EXTENSION_ORDER, EXTENSION_TEXT, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATE_BY, LAST_UPDATE_TIME) values ('disable ref integrity','java','org.jumpmind.symmetric.load.IReloadListener','ALL',1,1,'import org.jumpmind.db.sql.ISqlTransaction;
import org.jumpmind.symmetric.ISymmetricEngine;
import org.jumpmind.symmetric.ext.ISymmetricEngineAware;
import org.jumpmind.symmetric.load.IReloadListener;
import org.jumpmind.symmetric.model.Node;

public class MyReloadListener implements IReloadListener, ISymmetricEngineAware {

    ISymmetricEngine engine;

    @Override
    public void setSymmetricEngine(ISymmetricEngine engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeReload(ISqlTransaction transaction, Node node, long loadId) {
        engine.getDataService().insertSqlEvent(transaction, node, "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;", true, loadId, "initial load");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterReload(ISqlTransaction transaction, Node node, long loadId) {
        engine.getDataService().insertSqlEvent(transaction, node, "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;", true, loadId, "initial load");
    }

}
',{ts '2015-03-09 20:21:02.432'},'no_user',{ts '2015-03-09 20:23:59.098'});
```

also without success.

**UPDATE**:

There is option in settings:

```
create.table.without.foreign.keys
```

http://www.symmetricds.org/issues/view.php?id=2282

Comment: why don't you create the client schema on the mysql db yourself before running symmetricDs?

Comment: the schema in postgres may change over time and I would like it will be tracked automatically.